# Error al ejecutar comando usando "insert into"

Tags: ms-access

hice un formulario de captura en Access, usando variables temporales para la captura de información, al oprimir el boton guardar me manda este error:

> La expresión al hacer clic que especifico como valor de propiedad de evento produjo el error Se esperaba: expresion

El codigo es este:

```
Private Sub Btn_Guardar_Click()
Dim SQL As String
  SQL = "INSERT INTO AS_Investigaciones(F_REGISTRO,GERENCIA,NOMBRE)VALUES('#variabletemporal.F_REGISTRO#','variabletemporal.GERENCIA','variabletemporal.NOMBRE')"
End Sub
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y que se supone que queres que haga eso? y donde esta eso? y esto que lenguaje es? y ese titulo que quiere decir? la pregunta va en la pregunta... no en el titulo... por favor, tene en cuenta que no sabemos nada de tu problema...

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya hice lo que me recomendaste, saludos

Comment: ok... pero ese codigo que esta ahi, solo declara un string... nadie esta ejecutando ese insert... o tenes mas codigo?